# How can I get the text of a HTML subclass with a python webcrawler? The output seems to be an empty array

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to crawl text from a subclass within the

HTML tag with BeautifulSoup, but the output is an empty array.

I already tried to use only the upper class (msg-content-cell) and only the sub class (f1vbk p-msg-head-body) without the tag p at the end.

This is my python program:

```
class CrawledArticle():
def __init__(self, heading, message):
    self.heading = heading
    self.message = message

class ArticleFetcher():
def fetch(self):
    url = "https://www.verkehrsinformation.de/?road=A8&region=%25"
    articles = []
    time.sleep(1)
    r = requests.get(url)  
    doc = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

    for heading in doc.select(".td-msg-head-heading"):
        heading = heading.select(".td-msg-head-heading")
        for message in doc.select(".msg-content-cell"):
            message = message.select(".msg-content-cell .f1vbk p-msg-head-body p")

            crawled = CrawledArticle(heading, message)
            articles.append(crawled)

    return articles
```

Here is the extract from the HTML source code where I want to crawl the text "zwischen Beratzhausen (95) und Parsberg (94)"

```
 </div>
        <div id="a3itHKyCfOGlFAIL" class="table-row newmsg">
        <div class="msg-content-cell">
            <div class="row bg-white cursor-pointer" onclick="window.location.href='/staumeldung/?token=a3itHKyCfOGlFAIL&sp=ro:%|re:2|pg:1'">
                <div class="td-msg-head-heading">
                    <p class="f1vbk p-msg-head-heading">
                        A3 Passau Richtung Nürnberg:
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="td-msg-head-info">
                    &nbsp;                    </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row bg-white cursor-pointer" onclick="window.location.href='/staumeldung/?token=a3itHKyCfOGlFAIL&sp=ro:%|re:2|pg:1'">
                <p class="f1vbk p-msg-head-body">
                    zwischen Beratzhausen (95) und Parsberg (94) Wanderbaustelle.&nbsp;
                    <!--<a class="extendlink l1vbku">Mehr</a>...//-->
                </p>
                <p class="p-msg-head-body pull-right f1vbk">
                                        <a class="extendlink l1vbku">Kartenansicht</a>&nbsp;|
                    <a class="extendlink l1vbku">Alle Details</a>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
        </div>
```

I expect to crawl the text from the subclass "f1vbk p-msg-head-body" within the

HTML tag, but the output is an empty array.

Where is the difference compared to the class "td-msg-head-heading" and how can I get the plain text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you want to do with classes but I would select for the parent element of header and message and loop those extracting header and message as children. Not sure why you are including a sleep in there.

P.S. Use more descriptive variable names than I have.

```
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, time

class CrawledArticle():

    def __init__(self, heading, message):
        self.heading = heading
        self.message = message

class ArticleFetcher():

    def fetch(self):
        url = "https://www.verkehrsinformation.de/?road=A8&region=%25"
        articles = []
        time.sleep(1)
        r = requests.get(url)  
        doc = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "lxml")

        for item in doc.select('.msg-content-cell'):
            heading = item.select_one('.p-msg-head-heading').text.strip()
            message = item.select_one('.msg-content-cell .p-msg-head-body:not(.pull-right)').text.strip()
            crawled = CrawledArticle(heading, message)
            articles.append(crawled)

        return articles

a = ArticleFetcher()
b = a.fetch()
for item in b:
    print(item.heading,'\n' ,item.message)
```

---

**Sample output:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me! This was exactly the output I wanted to achieve. Actually I wanted to select the sub class, but didn´t know how to properly do this. The sleep in there is included so as not to bombard the website with requests.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
doc.find("p", class_="f1vbk p-msg-head-body").string
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but unfortunately the output is now "None", but still not the desired text.

Comment: May it be the case that the "&nbsp" in the HTML source code causes the issue due to the "empty" output?